# Dependabot version 2 and Github Package

Tags: github, dependabot

Before I used `Dependabot Preview`.

Days ago, I migrated to the new version of `Dependabot Native`, however, now it is not accessing `Github Packages` and so, the packages that I have as git modules (it used to work out of the box with Dependabot Preview)

This is my code:

```
version: 2
registries:
  npm-registry-npm-pkg-github-com:
    type: npm-registry
    url: https://npm.pkg.github.com
    token: "${{secrets.NPM_REGISTRY_NPM_PKG_GITHUB_COM_TOKEN}}"

updates:
- package-ecosystem: npm
  directory: "/"
  schedule:
    interval: daily
    time: "09:00"
    timezone: America/Los_Angeles
  open-pull-requests-limit: 12
  registries:
  - npm-registry-npm-pkg-github-com
```

I have the secret `NPM_REGISTRY_NPM_PKG_GITHUB_COM_TOKEN` in my Repo Secrets.

I'd appreciate help.

Comment: Dont know what is happening, but your config looks almost the same from blog post, https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-15-dependabot-private-registry-support-public-beta/